# Minimum IAM Permissions for writing to a BigQuery table?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I'd like to have a job write to a *single* BigQuery table. I thought the IAM permissions would be simple, granting `BigQuery Jobs User` role to the Service Account on the respective table, but I'm getting the error.

`Access Denied: Project <your-project>: User does not have bigquery.jobs.create permission in project <your-project>`

Is there a way to avoid granting a Service Account access to an entire project, when you only want to grant access to a single table in a single dataset? How does one apply the Principle of Least Privilege in GCP BigQuery?

Code making the query:

```
const bigquery = new BigQuery({projectId});
await bigquery
  .dataset(datasetId)
  .table(tableId, {location: DATASET_LOCATION})
  .load(fileRef);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can grant access at [Table level](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/table-access-controls-intro) if needed. However, the issue you are facing is that the Service Account or any user in general need to have a proper permission to actually **create a job**. In other words, the queries run in projects that are linked to a Billing account. Someone needs to pay for it.

The role "BigQuery Job User" provides permissions to run jobs, including queries, within the project. But doesn't give you access to data.

You have to give bigquery.jobUser at project level, and then bigquery.dataViewer to the specific dataset or table. More information about BQ access control in [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control).

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a missing piece of the NodeJS library. I didn't find a workaround to achieve what I want (In the same time, I'm very bad in NodeJS).

In GO, I found what you need

```
    bq,err := bigquery.NewClient(ctx, "myRunningProject")
    bq.DatasetInProject("targetProject", "dataset").Table("table").LoaderFrom(...)
```

You initiate the client in your billable project, where you are Job User. And when you build your dataset/table path, you use a different project.

You can open a feature request on the BigQuery NodeJS library.